# How to call a constant from a func in another func

Tags: swift

I’m new in swift and have a  question .

I made a `UITextField` in a `func` programmatically and I want to call it in another `func` like:

```
func alertForEmptyField {
    if textfield == nill { 
        ...
    }
}
```

But I can’t call my textfield of course because it is in another `func`, but my silly question is how can I call it ?

I don’t want to make my constants in `viewDidLoad` because those are more than 20 constants for that reason I made them separately in separate `func`.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read up on the concept of scope. The Apple Swift iBook covers this quite well. I suggest reading the first few chapters of that book to get a better grounding. (You will struggle until you get this concept, so it's worth spending as much time as it takes to get it before moving on.)

If you define a variable or let constant inside a function, it is a **local** variable, and it ceases to exist when you exit the function. If that variable/constant contains an object, and that's the only reference to that object, it will get deallocated once the function returns. You need to move your variables/constants outside of your functions (and probably make them instance variables) if you want them to be accessible from other instance methods in your class.

Comment: Yes thank you so much I forgot return it works now 

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that. If you need to access variable you should return it. Then you can assign it to variable, constant or property.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply it wirks now 